# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error when using ItemTouchHelper in recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I've read all the stackoverflows with this theme so far and the problem is not solved.
I have an  ItemTouchHelper :

```
ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)
         {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            mNotes.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });`enter code here`
```

that attached to recyclerView with this adapter :

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

List<Note> notes;
Context context;
public NotesAdapter(List<Note> notes, Context context) {
    this.notes = notes;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setNotes(List<Note> notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.note_list_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(notes.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notes.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView title, text, date;
    Note mNote;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_item_title);
        text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_item_text);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_item_date);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = NoteEditActivity.newIntent(context, mNote);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void bind(Note note) {
        mNote = note;
        text.setText(note.getText());
        title.setText(note.getTitle());
        date.setText(note.getDate().toString());
    }
}
```

}

and recyclerView have LinearLayoutManager.
when i tried to swipe i got this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{ac354a70 position=10 id=-1, oldPos=10, pLpos:-1 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{aba0d698 VFED.... .F....I. 0,0-1080,1581 #7f08008b app:id/recycler_view}, adapter:com.example.notebook_v2.NotesAdapter@ac317680, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@aba66738, context:com.example.notebook_v2.NoteListActivity@ab9fd968
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5715)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5898)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3875)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3639)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(
```

I don't know what to do and the internet has not helped me so far.`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error is because you're calling `notifyItemChanged` instead of `notifyItemRemoved`. You are deleting an item from `mNotes` so your list has one item less than before. When you call `notifyItemChanged`, it tells the adapter that you just changed an item so nothing has removed. The adapter looks for last item to load, but there is no item there!

Try using this:

```
ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            0,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)
     {
        @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull ViewHolder 
                viewHolder, @NonNull ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        mNotes.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }
});`enter code here`
```